# Vertical scrolling in div animation by changing css top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to set up horizontal slider. I have div with `overflow: hidden` and inside I have 16 divs with height of 60px. Parent div has height so you can see only 4 childs at the time.

Now I want to change childs `top:` css to make them slide up and 4 new come from bottom.

Here's what I've done so far

```
lastAddedService.getLastAdded()
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.lastAddedElements = response.data;

        var i = 0, g = 0, c = 0, p = 0;
        var k = 1, b = 1, h = 1;

        var slider = {
            step: 1,
            positionTop: 0,
            init: function (step) {
                var that = this;
                el[0].querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(function (element) {
                    if(step === 1) {
                        if(i < 16) {
                            that.positionTop = i * 60;
                            i++;
                            return angular.element(element).css('top', that.positionTop);
                        }
                    }
                    if(step === 2) {
                        if(i < 4) {
                            that.positionTop = k * 60 * -1;
                            i++; k++;
                            return angular.element(element).css('top', that.positionTop);
                        }
                        if(i >= 4) {
                            k = 0;
                            that.positionTop = g * 60;
                            i++; g++;
                            return angular.element(element).css('top', that.positionTop);
                        }
                    }
                    if(step === 3) {
                        if(i < 8) {
                            that.positionTop = b * 60 * -1;
                            i++; b++;
                            return angular.element(element).css('top', that.positionTop);
                        }
                        if(i >= 8) {
                            that.positionTop = c * 60;
                            i++; c++;
                            return angular.element(element).css('top', that.positionTop);
                        }
                    }
                    if(step === 4) {
                        if(i < 12) {
                            that.positionTop = h * 60 * -1;
                            i++; h++;
                            return angular.element(element).css('top', that.positionTop);
                        }
                        if(i >= 12) {
                            that.positionTop = p * 60;
                            i++; p++;
                            return angular.element(element).css('top', that.positionTop);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            changeSlide: function (step) {
                this.step = step;
                this.init(this.step);
            }
        };

        $timeout(function () {
            slider.changeSlide(1);
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                var q = 1;
                q++;
                slider.changeSlide(q);
                if(q === 4) {
                    q = 1;
                }
            }, 5000);
        }, 5000);

    }, function (err) {
        console.log('error getting last added');
    });
}
```

So I'm gathering records from backend and then there is this slider object which has logic which I explained above.

Backend call works fine, I did console response and it's 16 records which I display in layout layer later on. Question is mainly about the logic for this sliding object.

I'm using `$timeout` to start code work because this code is indeed in angularJS directive and NodeList which I get by `querySelectorAll` would be empty otherwise because it's evaluated after async backend call finish and then DOM is fully loaded. But it's not really relevant to real logic of this script, it's just additional info.

- This code looks very bad to me. How I can improve it?
- It's starting to update top after around 20 seconds and 1 div has 960px I don't know why.
- It's not reseting this variables values so it doesn't loop but it increase `top` further and further.

I add HTML from my directive if anyone want to reproduce issue

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row u-no-margin">
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-xs-11">
            <h2 class="main__heading">
                Ostatnio dodane
            </h2>
            <div class="main__last-added-field">
                <div class="main__last-added a" data-ng-repeat="n in lastAddedElements">
                    <div class="row u-no-margin main__last-added-container">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <h4 class="main__last-added-heading">
                                {{ n.data.attributes.price }}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-8 u-no-padding">
                            <h4 class="main__last-added-heading u-no-padding">
                                {{ n.data.attributes.name }}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn__primary">
                                Zobacz
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-1">
            <div class="main__last-added-dot-container">
                <span class="main__last-added-dot main__last-added-dot--active"></span>
                <span class="main__last-added-dot"></span>
                <span class="main__last-added-dot"></span>
                <span class="main__last-added-dot"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code is within directive `link: function` and the templateUrl is above HTML code.

---

---

---

** EDIT **

---

---

---

I update question I add plunker showing issue and I explain one more, step by step what I want to accomplish.

- Step1: all element has `top: x` css so they are align vertically. I'm using `overflow: hidden` on parent so you see only 4 and 12 are hidden below like this

[image: alt]

- Step2 I move first 4 element to `top: -x` so you don't see first 4 and element 5,6,7,8 take their place so elements 5,6,7,8 now slide to the top and first 4 are hidden.
- step 3 same as Step2: elements 5,6,7,8 move to negative top and you now see elements 9,10,11,12
- step 4 same as Step3: elements 9,10,11,12 move to negative top and you now see elements 13,14,15,16

[here's demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ud2wWoD87WqmSRDy9A4i?p=preview)

I don't know why but in plunker it doesn't udpate css top of elements at all.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: the only missing code here is HTML which i thought would be easy to reproduce. However as you wish I edit my question and add html

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle or stackblitz for your code

Comment: take a look at edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it with this code:

```
<div class="main__last-added a"
     data-ng-repeat="n in lastAddedElements"
     data-order="{{ $index+1 }}">
```

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('igt')
        .directive('lastAdded', Directive);

    Directive.$inject = ['$timeout', 'lastAddedService'];

    function Directive($timeout, lastAddedService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                destiny: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'html/directives/lastAdded.html',
            link: function ($scope, el) {
                lastAddedService.getLastAdded()
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.lastAddedElements = response.data;
                        $scope.slider = {
                            increment: 0,
                            step: 1,
                            positionTop: 0,
                            init: function (step) {
                                var that = this;
                                var elements = el[0].querySelectorAll('.a');
                                if(step === 1) {
                                    console.log('run step 1 ..............');
                                    this.step = 1;
                                    elements.forEach(function (e) {
                                        var order = angular.element(e).attr('data-order');
                                        if(order <= 16) {
                                            that.positionTop = order * 60 - 60;
                                            return angular.element(e).css('top', that.positionTop);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                if(step === 2) {
                                    console.log('run step 2 ..............');
                                    this.step = 2;
                                    elements.forEach(function (e) {
                                        var order = angular.element(e).attr('data-order');
                                        if (order <= 4) {
                                            that.positionTop = order * 60 * -1;
                                            return angular.element(e).css('top', that.positionTop);
                                        }
                                        if (order > 4) {
                                            that.positionTop = that.increment * 60;
                                            that.increment++;
                                            console.log(that.increment);
                                            if (that.increment === 12) {
                                                that.increment = 0;
                                                console.log('reset inc in step 2');
                                            }
                                            return angular.element(e).css('top', that.positionTop);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                if(step === 3) {
                                    console.log('run step 3 ..............');
                                    this.step = 3;
                                    elements.forEach(function (e) {
                                        var order = angular.element(e).attr('data-order');
                                        if (order <= 8) {
                                            that.positionTop = order * 60 * -1;
                                            return angular.element(e).css('top', that.positionTop);
                                        }
                                        if (order > 8) {
                                            that.positionTop = that.increment * 60;
                                            that.increment++;
                                            console.log(that.increment);
                                            if (that.increment === 8) {
                                                that.increment = 0;
                                                console.log('reset inc in step 3');
                                            }
                                            return angular.element(e).css('top', that.positionTop);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                if(step === 4) {
                                    console.log('run step 4 ..............');
                                    this.step = 4;
                                    elements.forEach(function (e) {
                                        var order = angular.element(e).attr('data-order');
                                        if (order <= 12) {
                                            that.positionTop = order * 60 * -1;
                                            return angular.element(e).css('top', that.positionTop);
                                        }
                                        if (order > 12) {
                                            that.positionTop = that.increment * 60;
                                            that.increment++;
                                            console.log(that.increment);
                                            if (that.increment === 4) {
                                                that.increment = 0;
                                                console.log('reset inc in step 4');
                                            }
                                            return angular.element(e).css('top', that.positionTop);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            changeSlide: function (step) {
                                this.step = step;
                                this.init(this.step);
                            }
                        };

                        $timeout(function () {
                            var i = 1;
                            $scope.slider.changeSlide(i);
                            setInterval(function () {
                                i++; if(i === 5) i = 1;
                                $scope.slider.changeSlide(i);
                            }, 5000);
                        });

                    }, function (err) {
                        console.log('error getting last added: ' + err);
                    });
            }

        }
    }

})();
```

But this code still look very lame although it's a bit better than first version. I feel like it can be done in much much simplier way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend that you use a bootstrap only solution for your html/css view because its responsive, tested and you will have cleaner code.

I have made some modification to your slider logic in a way that the logic is the as if your slider were a pagination directive.

Basically, you divide your data into pages and then you keep track of the current page to be displayed on the view.

In your elements directive you use two filters on the data (startFrom, limitTo). The 'limitTo' is a built-in filter in Angular and 'startFrom' is a custom filter that you have to create.

```
<div class="" data-ng-repeat="n in elements | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
```

This is just an ideia that might help you refactor you code such that you won't need css positioning to determine which items will be displayed. Here is my demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/IROsQWr5z4oYgZzmR2GF?p=preview

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's nice idea but I will not be able to add animation of scrolling to that because there is no scroll indeed. So thanks for idea but I would rather use css top property

Comment: Of course you can add animation ! You just need to create a class and assign this class to the specific items you want to animate using `$(...)addClass(active)` and still keep track of your current pagination page.This article will provide the css you need in order to do this http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/